# "Регистрация в конференции". Правильно ли?

Tags: согласование

Мне казалось, что правильно "регистрация на конференцию". Но на сайте мероприятия написано "регистрация в конференции".

Answer (score 3):

Из словаря сочетаемости(Институт русского языка АН):
Участие...**в конференции**. Подготовка ...**к конференции**. Поездка, приглашение ... **на конференцию**. Выступление ...**на конференции**.

**В конференции** (принять участие, участвовать...) **К конференции** (готовиться...). **На конференцию** (прийти, приехать,прислать, пригласить...). **На конференции** (выступить, обсуждать...). **С конференции** (уехать, вернуться...). (Жирный шрифт и многоточия, как в словаре).

Comment: Вопрос в том, к чему отнести "регистрацию". Регистрация "во что?" ("куда") - это не участие "в чем". Т.е. приведенная цитата сама по себе мало о чем говорит.  
Хотя скорее всего регистрация (регистрироваться) здесь в ряду "прийти", "приехать" и проч...

Comment: Я вполне согласна с Вашим ответом. Регистрация НА конференцию. Согласна и в том, что с изменением значения слова меняется и управление. Конференция онлайн или по телефону, это, скорее, полилог, чем собрание представителей. Отсюда и изменение управления.

Comment: @Ларf, да я вообще не думал о своем ответе, я за них не держусь, если есть причины отказаться.   
  
Мне хотелось понять, что следует из непосредсвенно их цитаты, потом уж разбираться с ответами при необходимости. И аот тут я не понял, можно ли эту цитату как-то прямо использовать в разбираемом вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы правильно выбрать предлог, можно:

1. обратиться к словарю, чтобы определиться с дефиницией слова, предлог к которому вызвал затруднение;
2. рассмотреть примеры употребления этого слова (в словарной статье, как правило, они приводятся).

В нашем случае:

> КОНФЕРЕНЦИЯ, -и; ж. [лат. conferentiа]
> Собрание, совещание представителей
> каких-л. государств, партийных,
> общественных, научных и т.п.
> организаций для обсуждения и решения
> каких-л. вопросов.

[link text](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EA%EE%ED%F4%E5%F0%E5%ED%F6%E8%FF)

В этой же словарной статье даны примеры:

> Участвовать в конференции. Послать
> тезисы, заявку для участия в
> конференции.

Делаем вывод: *регистрация в конференции* — употреблено верно.

Comment: >Делаем вывод: регистрация в конференции — употреблено верно.

Откуда такой странный вывод?

Comment: "Безработному программеру" этого не понять.

Comment: Я тоже не  понимаю логику Марины. Если правильно "участвовать В конференции", это еще не значит , что регистрация В конференцию тоже верно. А как же со словами "поехать", "пригласить" - тоже В конференцию?

Определенного падежа требует глагол, а не управляемое существительное.

Answer (score 1):

Это смотря какая конференция.  
Если обычная, какие были до появления всяких интернетов и видеотелефонов, то да, "регистрация на конференцию". Причем - предварительная. 
А вот то, что написано на сайте, скорее всего означает уже проходящую интернет-конференцию, НА которую не надо ехать, но В которую надо просто войти, только зарегистировавшись.  
Не поручусь, что это нормативно, но мне понятно.

Comment: Судя по всему, конференция будет  в феврале.

Comment: Да? я чего-то там не понял?
Ну да ладно. Тогда я тоже несколько сомневаюсь в правильности. К сожалению, только субъективно, формальных причин запретить "регистрацию в конференцию", которая еще только будет проходить, я не вижу. Но не нравится, поскольку тогда она ничем (с точки зрения грамматики) не отличается от обычной, рекнистрироваться положено *на корорую*.